# skip mailing labels -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

Example:

> As the title implies, this book is about using Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) to enhance the power of Access databases. If you want Access to print words on a check, **skip mailing labels** that you’ve already used, or manipulate data behind the scenes, you have to write VBA code.

First of all, what are ***mailing labels***? And secondly, what does ***skip mailing labels*** mean exactly?

Comment: What are mailing labels? [Here is a picture](http://www.adkad.com/images/labels-irrigation-scheduling-software-2.png) of a sheet of mailing labels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To "skip" means to "hop over".  A mailing label is an adhesive label on which a (snail) mail address is printed. The label is attached to an envelope before the letter is put in the mailbox or given to the post office.  These labels are available in sheets, with several columns and rows of such labels.  If the first three rows of labels were already printed, say, but the remaining labels were blank, then you could write a program to "skip" the first three rows and begin printing at the fourth row.